# Windows GUI vs. Linux CLI if you are a visually impaired programmer?

Tags: linux, windows, user-interface

I am visually impaired and have used Windows my whole life and I rarely use the command prompt and mostly use the GUI with the Windows 7 magnifying glass. However, sometimes I wish that I could work faster, easier and more efficently as a programmer without straining my eyes. I wonder if it would be easier to learn Linux and just use the Linux terminal CLI instead of having to look for and icons and such in the Windows GUI. WHat do you think would be the best option in the long run as a programmer if you are visually impaired? Should I leave Windows and learn the Linux terminal instead of using the annoyng magnifying glass in Windows GUI? Do many visually impaired/blind programmers prefer Linux terminal more than the Windows GUI? Any tips? Is there a free magnifying tool that works good in Linux like in Windows? Does Linux have support for visually impaired programmers/developers? I already know that there is something called Vinux but I want other answers please.

Comment: The question as it is written implies opinion based answers and will be closed especially as it is off-topic to SO. Anyway... Have you tried audio/voice helpers?

Answer (score 1):

The specific distinction between the two, notably ANY GUI and CLI, is that in a GUI, many have the issue that you have to "aim" at thing (i.e with the mouse).

Whereas CLIs tend to be deterministic from the keyboard (type in your command, Go Forward 3 Characters with an arrow key, etc.)

Many GUI have lots of command shortcuts making keyboard navigation much more realistic.

So, in those cases, it's not an either/or thing.

Obviously the advantage of the keyboard navigation is that "you now what to do", and can use your typing skills to do it (assuming you have the keyboard memorized) vs search for the rectangle of screen space that you need to place the arrow of the mouse.

So, if you're comfortable with your Windows tools, see if there are application short cuts you can use, or barring that, there are external "Macro" programs that help augment the keyboard as well.

You may well be able to find a happy medium for your work.

Answer (score 1):

Linux (particularly Gnome, AFAIU) has good support for impaired users. You'd have to try the alternatives and see what works best for you. Your decision will be based on interface (be it GUI or CLI, on Linux there are several alternatives), on the availability of programs for your needs, and (last but certainly not least) your own tastes.

In any case, get in touch with other users around you using similar setups. A tame geek is always handy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Will that it depends how well you know the keyboard. I use the command line in Linux on a regular basis. I am much quicker with the command line. Most Linux terminals give you a way to increase the font size. I do that sometimes when I am trying to find problems in my code.